# change color of id when smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how would i add onto this smooth scrolling function to change the color of the id that is scrolled to?

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a working demo or fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of the font-color add this

```
 target.css('color', 'red');
```

after

```
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
```

or inside the callback-function of the animation:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 1000, function(){
    target.css('color', 'red');
});
```

If you want to clear the other links, you can use:

```
$('a[name]').css('color', 'black');
```

**Update**

In your case you are adding the color to a `p`-tag. So you have to change your selector:

```
$("p[id^='faq_']").css('color', '#707070');
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q8n8ovbn/3/)

**Reference**

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: got it.  one more question: how do i get it to clear the color the next time the function is called (ie the next time i click a link to an anchor)?

Comment: thanks. i added it to this [page](http://gioventu.nyc/pages/frequently-asked-questions) but still not clearing the black. any ideas? appreciate your help.

Comment: @rs202 I updated my answer according to your html-markup

Answer (score 0):

you already have the target, so all you need to do now is pass in the complete callback function to the animate method:

```
$('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, {
        duration: 500,
        complete: function () {
          // add a new class to trigger multiple style attributes of the selector
          target.className = "new-color";
        }
      });
```

Comment: why am i being down voted? I was literally the first person to suggest adding anything to the callback.

Comment: got it.  one more question: how do i get it to clear the color the next time the function is called (ie the next time i click a link to an anchor)?

Comment: Empiric's solution would work, but it would change all anchor tags to black that have a name attribute in the tag (which is ok if you expect that generality).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do it at the same time as or after the scroll? To do it at the same time, add this just before the "return false;".

```
target.css("color","red")
```

You'll also need to change it back to normal afterwards. This depends on how many elements will be "targetable", but the best approach might be to give them each a class that's the same.

Comment: ok this is great. one more question: how do i get it to clear the color the next time the function is called (ie the next time i click a link to an anchor)?

Comment: Have a look at the answer from @empiric below. That's probably the simplest solution, granted that all your anchor elements are the same color.